# C++ Data Parsing query

Tags: c++

Hello guys i hope you could enlighten me with this issue i am facing!

**Initial Output:**
The sample text file is below and the format is as follow (Item Desc:Price:Quantity:Date).

- STRAW:10:10:11NOV1991
- BARLEY:5.10:5:19OCT1923
- CHOCOLATE:50:50:11NOV1991

I am required to print out a daily summary report of the total amt of sales on that day. Based on the sample above, the result will be on 11 NOV 1991 the total amt of sales(2 items) will be 60 while on 19OCT1923 the total amt of sales(1 item) will be 5.

**Desired Output:**

- 11Nov1991 Total amt of sales:60
- 19Oct1923 Total amt of sales:5

My question is, how do i generate the code to show only one unique date with the total amount of sales? I have created a loop to check if that a **certain year exist** for testing purposes but it isn't working. I want it to be able to iterate through a file and check if a certain year exist and if it exist already, the next vector element that has the same year won't be written to a file but instead only the item price will be added. Below is the code i am trying to implement.

```
ifstream readReport("DailyReport.txt");
ofstream writeDailyReport("EditedDailyReport.txt");


    string temp1 = "";


                        //Read from empty report.txt              
                        while(getline(readReport,temp1))
                        {


                            for(int i=0; i < itemDescVec.size(); i++)
                                {   

                                 stringstream streamYearSS;
                                 streamYearSS << itemDescVec[i].dateYear;
                                 string stringYear = streamYearSS.str();


                                size_t found1 = temp1.find(stringYear);

                                //If can find year
                                if (found1 != string::npos )
                                {


                                    cout << "Can find" << endl;




                                }

                                //If cannot find year
                                else if (found1 == string::npos )
                                {


                                    cout << "Cannot find" << endl;
                                      writeDailyReport << itemDescVec[i].itemDescription << ":" << itemDescVec[i].unitPrice << ":" 
                                       << itemDescVec[i].quantity << ":" << itemDescVec[i].dateDay << "/" << itemDescVec[i].dateMonth << "/" << itemDescVec[i].dateYear  
                                      << endl; 

                                } 



                            }

                        }


        readReport.close();
        writeDailyReport.close();


    remove("DailyReport.txt");
    rename("EditedDailyReport.txt", "DailyReport.txt");
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. You should show us the code you've tried so far, and the problem you are facing. Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing the exact data structure you have so far. So I can't help unless you show your current code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use your own object to store the data - then you can write, for example, `salesRecord.quantity` (or `salesRecord.getQuantity()` if you have written a getter) instead of `salesrecord.at(2)`. This is a lot more readable and is better practice than remembering that 2 = quantity (etc.).

Now as to your actual question... I would say something like this:

- Iterate over the list. For each item:

  1. Check if the date of the item has already been added to your new list.
  2. If the date does not already exist, simply add the item in its entireity.
  3. If it does already exist, edit the existing item such that `previousQuantity += quantityToAdd`

On the sorted list

```
BARLEY:5.10:5:19OCT1923
STRAW:10:10:11NOV1991
CHOCOLATE:50:50:11NOV1991
```

this would work as follows:

1. Try to add barley data - nothing for that date so far, so add it:

   ```
   19OCT1923 - 5 units
   ```
2. Try to add strawberry data - nothing for that date so far, so add it:

   ```
   19OCT1923 - 5 units
   11NOV1991 - 10 units
   ```
3. Try to add chocolate data - 11NOV1991 already exists, so add 50 to the 10 that's already there:

   ```
   19OCT1923 - 5 units
   11NOV1991 - 60 units
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, thats real helpful. i will try and report back if it's successful!

Comment: hi there, i did it using STL map using date as a unique key eventually. Nonetheless, thank you for the help:)

Comment: Does that add the units correctly (i.e. say '60' for the 50+10 case)?

Comment: Great :) Maybe you should consider answering your own question, so that if someone later has a similar problem, they can see a helpful solution. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)